# How can I access raw sensor data from a nearby device without deploying an app to the device?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-sensors, bluetooth-gatt

My Android application needs to get the raw sensor data, such as the accelerometer readings, on a device other than the one running the program (e.g., a Huawei Watch, Google Pixel watch, Samsung Watch, or any smartwatch within a 5-meter distance). The optimal plan would not require deploying any program onto the smartwatch device, as that would be highly inconvenient for the promotion of the product.

Is there any way to access raw sensor data on another device without deploying an application to the other device?

I initially planned to use the Google Fit API, since its [documentation says that it can access data sources on companian devices](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/sensors#:%7E:text=The%20Sensors%20API%20lets%20you,longer%20receive%20raw%20sensor%20data.). But as the API is deprecated and is [scheduled to be completely turned down](https://developers.google.com/fit/android#:%7E:text=will%20be%20turned%20down%20at%20the%20end%20of%202024) soon, this plan can not be depended upon under long-term considerations (unless, of course, there is any way to make the API available still after the turndown).

Apparently, the Google Fit API uses Bluetooth Low Energy to access sensor data on other devices (I'm not quite sure of this. Is it so?). So I wonder if using Bluetooth directly is an option to meet my goal. Is it possible to use Bluetooth to access raw sensor data, given that the other device implemented a standard Bluetooth Low Energy GATT profile?

Comment: Totally depends on the device.  In the case of a device sending BLE signals, then it's broadcasting its information to anyone who wants to listen.  So yes, you could read that.  You'd need to know the format of the data to interpret it though, which may or may not be documented, and could differ for every device.

Comment: @GabeSechan I was hoping that there is some universal (or at least widely applicable) way to get raw sensor data, so that the user can use the program with a large selection of sensor devices.

Comment: Not really.  At least not without being more specific.  These sensors are low energy and using BLE, they aren't going to be outputting JSON or some other fancy format.  It's binary data, in a compact format.  There *might* be a standard for a particular type of sensor, like an accelerometer.  But it won't be one standard across all sensor types.